# How to know closest iBeacon

Tags: android, ios, cordova, ibeacon

I m using Cordova  making ios/android apps.I m using this plugin for iBeacon ranging  https://github.com/petermetz/cordova-plugin-ibeacon. its works no problem with this.
but I have problem with know closest beacon.

```
{
"region": {
    "typeName": "BeaconRegion",
    "identifier": "BeaconTest",
    "uuid": "8deefbb9-f738-4297-8040-96668bb44281"
},
"beacons": [
    {
        "proximity": "ProximityImmediate",
        "tx": -59,
        "rssi": -46,
        "uuid": "8deefbb9-f738-4297-8040-96668bb44281",
        "accuracy": 0.08,
        "minor": 4370,
        "major": 1
    },
    {
        "proximity": "ProximityNear",
        "tx": -59,
        "rssi": -57,
        "uuid": "8deefbb9-f738-4297-8040-96668bb44281",
        "accuracy": 0.71,
        "minor": 4358,
        "major": 1
    }
],
"eventType": "didRangeBeaconsInRegion"
```

}

in here I know which one is closest beacon.but sometimes  proximity value is same.How to know which one closest ? rssi or something which one effected ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to know the closest iBeacon](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23290544/how-to-know-the-closest-ibeacon)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will find your answer here (as TX and RSSI concepts are not platform specific):

https://community.estimote.com/hc/en-us/articles/201636913-Broadcasting-Power-RSSI-and-Measured-Power-explained

Have a look over here too:
[Estimating beacon proximity/distance based on RSSI - Bluetooth LE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22784516/estimating-beacon-proximity-distance-based-on-rssi-bluetooth-le)