# Proper way to find the closest beacon

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift, ibeacon

When the didRangeBeacons method is called, is the closest beacon beacons.first? Or is it the beacon in the list of beacons that has the lowest accuracy value? Are both correct? Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to know the closest iBeacon](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23290544/how-to-know-the-closest-ibeacon)

Answer (score 1):

While the list of beacons in the `didRangeBeacons:inRegion:` callback is sorted by the accuracy field (which actually measures distance in meters), there are a number of problems with relying on this:

- Sometimes beacons have an accuracy value of -1 if no RSSI (signal strength) samples were available in the past second.  This gives you incorrect results if you relay on the automatic sorting.
- Sometimes beacons drop out of the list if they aren't detected in the last second.  This is a common problem in noisy bluetooth environments and with infrequently transmitting beacons.

A more robust way to know the closest beacon is to implement an algorithm yourself that ignores accuracy values of -1 and is tolerant of temporary dropouts (say 5 seconds) in beacon detections.

Or course, this is just the beginning.  You can get even fancier by adding all kinds of other filters to tune it to your exact use case.  Without over complicating things, here's some Swift code I use to the basics:

```
let expirationTimeSecs = 5.0
public var closestBeacon: CLBeacon? = nil
var trackedBeacons: Dictionary<String, CLBeacon>
var trackedBeaconTimes: Dictionary<String, NSDate>

override init() {
  trackedBeacons = Dictionary<String, CLBeacon>()
  trackedBeaconTimes = Dictionary<String, NSDate>()
}

public func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didRangeBeacons beacons: [CLBeacon], inRegion region: CLBeaconRegion) {
  let now = NSDate()
  for beacon in beacons {
    let key = keyForBeacon(beacon)
    if beacon.accuracy < 0 {
      NSLog("Ignoring beacon with negative distance")
    }
    else {
      trackedBeacons[key] = beacon
      if (trackedBeaconTimes[key] != nil) {
        trackedBeaconTimes[key] = now
      }
      else {
        trackedBeaconTimes[key] = now
      }
    }
  }
  purgeExpiredBeacons()
  calculateClosestBeacon()
}

func calculateClosestBeacon() {
  var changed = false
    // Initialize cloestBeaconCandidate to the latest tracked instance of current closest beacon
    var closestBeaconCandidate: CLBeacon?
    if closestBeacon != nil {
      let closestBeaconKey = keyForBeacon(closestBeacon!)
      for key in trackedBeacons.keys {
        if key == closestBeaconKey {
          closestBeaconCandidate = trackedBeacons[key]
        }
      }
    }

    for key in trackedBeacons.keys {
      var closer = false
      let beacon = trackedBeacons[key]
      if (beacon != closestBeaconCandidate) {
        if beacon!.accuracy > 0 {
          if closestBeaconCandidate == nil {
            closer = true
          }
          else if beacon!.accuracy < closestBeaconCandidate!.accuracy {
            closer = true
          }
        }
        if closer {
          closestBeaconCandidate = beacon
          changed = true
        }
      }
    }
    if (changed) {
      closestBeacon = closestBeaconCandidate
    }
}

func keyForBeacon(beacon: CLBeacon) -> String {
  return "\(beacon.proximityUUID.UUIDString) \(beacon.major) \(beacon.minor)"
}

func purgeExpiredBeacons() {
  let now = NSDate()
  var changed = false
  var newTrackedBeacons = Dictionary<String, CLBeacon>()
  var newTrackedBeaconTimes = Dictionary<String, NSDate>()
  for key in trackedBeacons.keys {
    let beacon = trackedBeacons[key]
    let lastSeenTime = trackedBeaconTimes[key]!
    if now.timeIntervalSinceDate(lastSeenTime) > expirationTimeSecs {
      NSLog("******* Expired seeing beacon: \(key) time interval is \(now.timeIntervalSinceDate(lastSeenTime))")
      changed = true
    }
    else {
      newTrackedBeacons[key] = beacon!
      newTrackedBeaconTimes[key] = lastSeenTime
    }
  }
  if changed {
    trackedBeacons = newTrackedBeacons
    trackedBeaconTimes = newTrackedBeaconTimes
  }
}
```

Comment: Right now I have my locationManager in the app delegate and then when it finds the closest beacon it sends a notification to the view controller to update the view accordingly. My question is, how would I implement the code you've written here into my current setup?

Comment: A great way to send beacon data from your `AppDelegate` to a `ViewController` do this is with `NotificationCenter`.  It is a bit off topic, and would take more space to explain than is available here, so it is probably worthy of a new question.  Here is a blog that discusses the basics:  https://www.andrewcbancroft.com/2014/10/08/fundamentals-of-nsnotificationcenter-in-swift/  The idea is that you can pass the closest beacon as data in the notifications's `userInfo` dictionary, so it can be processed by your `ViewController`

Answer (score 0):

Once you detect beacons, in order to see which is closest, you need to iterate through the beacons array in the `locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didRangeBeacons:(NSArray *)beacons inRegion:(CLBeaconRegion *)region` callback, and compare the accuracy property of each beacon. The beacon with the lowest accuracy value is the closest.