# How to find the shortest distance between multiple beacons?

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, altbeacon, beacon

I have 5-6 beacons on the one place (hall). I want to find the shortest distance between the multiples beacons then send the related notification to the nearest beacon. I am using Altbeacon library.

Please help me how to find nearest beacon then send the related notification?

Comment: Have you followed [this](https://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/samples.html) tutorial?

Comment: Yes @MadhukarHebbar I followed this tutorial. With help of this tutorial we can find only distance of each beacon but didn't find the nearest beacon.

Comment: You need to check with the shortest distance between the multiple beacon points. What you have tried till now?

Answer (score 0):

While there are no built-in tools to filter ranged beacons and determine the closest one using the Android Beacon Library (or iOS CoreLocation for that matter), it is possible to layer on your own filtering code.

[Here is an algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33055499/1461050) for doing this in Swift for iOS.  The same algorithm will work in Java with the Android Beacon Library.

The important things are to keep track of the closest beacon across ranging cycles, and only change the determination if a different beacon is significantly closer or the current closest beacon has not been detected in a number of seconds.

Comment: Thanks @davidgyoung I'm trying this algo

Comment: nope...it is not useful for me.. can you suggest me some othe option @davidgyoung